# Spring boot security is not working after deploying war file into external tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have defined tomcat dependency as mentioned below.

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

When I am running locally everything is working fine. So it is working fine only in embedded tomcat but not in external tomcat.

Frontend app is developed using Angular 7. Frontend build files are placed inside static folder in spring boot application.

Problem that I am facing is, Rest API's are not secured when it is deployed in external Apache tomcat.

Any help is appreciated.